# sf_guard_user can't save permission

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, sfguard

In `sf_guard_user` form when I try to modify fields and permission to an user, symfony told me "The item was updated successfully."

All fields are modified exept the permission.

What I have to check?

Comment: Can you show your form class's code please.
There are a few common issues I've seen with the sf_guard_user plugin and saving the permissions with forms. See these two posts:
http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/5867
http://itsmajax.com/2011/01/29/6-things-to-know-about-embedded-forms-in-symfony/